# How do I trigger a click event in a Jasmine unit test for an Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In my directive's `link` function:

```
$document.on('click.sortColumnList', function () {
    viewToggleController.closeSortColumnList();
    scope.$apply();
});
```

In my Jasmine unit test:

```
describe('document click', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.$document.triggerHandler('click.sortColumnList');
    });

    it('should tell the controller to close the sort column list', function () {
        expect(this.ctrlMock.closeSortColumnList).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should trigger a digest cycle', function () {
        expect(this.$scope.$apply).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

This is not actually triggering the event listener. The tests are failing with:

```
 Expected spy closeSortColumnList to have been called.
```

The spies are set up correctly, the problem is that the event listener is not firing.

What do you have to do to trigger an event on `$document` in a Jasmine Angular unit test?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to add [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) to your project they have [specific functions](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#event-spies) to accomplish what you need. Using this you can do something like the following:

```
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#some_element', 'click')
$('#some_element').click()
expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#some_element')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: how can you add jasmine-jquery to the project ?

Comment: @CMA I am not really sure of what your set up is, but if you are using the Karma test runner, just add the file location to the files section of the `karma.conf.js` file.

Comment: @CMA, I have never used Chutzpah before, but this link seems like it may be what you need. https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah-File-References.  I think you would want to set jasmine-jquery up through the file references.